# the a:hover:not() execption responds only to the .active class?

Tags: html, css, frontend

I created a navbar and divided into 3  sections:
1. id="menu"
2. id="fake" ( button to fill space)
3. id="social"

I basically want that the .active page and the fake button to not be included in the hover effect but it looks like if I create a .fake classe and try a:hover:not(.fake) it doesn't work.
And I was acutally wondering as well if it's possible to create more than one excpetion.

Here's the whole code

```css
body{
 font-family:'Skranji',sans-serif;
 font-size:100%;
 margin:0;
}
#nav{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 width:100%;
  height:35px;
 position:fixed;
 overflow-y:hidden;
 font-size:16px;
 letter-spacing:3px; 
  
 border-bottom-style:solid;
 border-bottom-width:1px;
 border-color:black;
}
#nav a:not(.active){
 background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.72);
}
#nav a.active{
 background-color:black;
 color:white; 
}
#nav a:hover:not(.active){
 background-color:rgba(128, 127, 127, 0.25);
 color:black;
}
/*#nav a.fake{
 background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.72);
}
nav a:hover:not(.fake){
 background-color:rgba(128, 127, 127, 0.25);
 color:black;
}*/



#menu{
 width:70%;
}
#fake{
 width:15%;
 display:block;
 float:left;
}
#social{
 width:15%;
 float:left;
}
#menu a{
 display:table;
 width:25%;
 float:left;
}
#fake a{
 width:100%;
 display:table;
}
#social a{
 float:right;
 width:33.33%;
}
#menu a,#social a,#fake a{
 text-decoration:none;  
 margin:0;
 padding:5px;
 color:white;
 text-align:center;
}
.rMargin{
 margin-right:10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->   
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Skranji" rel="stylesheet"> 
  </head>
  <body>
      
    <header>
      <div id="nav">
        <div id="menu">
          <a class="active" href="home.html"><i class="fas fa-home rMargin"></i>Home</a>
          <a href="blog.html"><i class="fas fa-globe rMargin"></i>Blog</a>
          <a href="learn.html"><i class="fas fa-code rMargin"></i>Learn</a>
          <a href="contactMe.html"><i class="fas fa-envelope rMargin"></i>Contact Me</a>  
        </div> 

        <div id="fake" >
          <a class="fake" href="#"><button style="visibility:hidden"></button></a>
        </div>

        <div id="social">               
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a> 
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>                                
        </div>
      </div>        
      </header>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-+d0P83n9kaQMCwj8F4RJB66tzIwOKmrdb46+porD/OvrJ+37WqIM7UoBtwHO6Nlg" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `a:not(.fake):hover`

Comment: no it doesn't work

Comment: I changed to code to show how it should work. "Home" is the active page so when I hover over it nothing happens. I wanted to obtain the same result on the fake button added between the "menu" and the "social"

Answer (score 0):

Just found the answer! For some reason a:hover:not() accepts only .active class I think, so in my personal case I needed to insert the active class in the element in which I needed the exception and then add another class to restyle it so that the element doesn't actually look like the .active class.
You'll need to look a bit into the code to understand but is actually a good way to go over the issue

```css
body{
 font-family:'Skranji',sans-serif;
 font-size:100%;
 margin:0;
}
#nav{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 width:100%;
 height:35px;
 position:fixed;
 overflow-y:hidden;
 font-size:16px;
 letter-spacing:3px; 
  
 border-bottom-style:solid;
 border-bottom-width:1px;
 border-color:black;
}
#nav a:not(.active){
 background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.72);
}
#nav a.active{
 background-color:black;
 color:white; 
}
#nav a:hover:not(.active){
 background-color:rgba(128, 127, 127, 0.25);
 color:black;
}
#nav a.fake{
 background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.72);
}



#menu{
 width:70%;
}
#fake{
 width:15%;
 display:block;
 float:left;
}
#social{
 width:15%;
 float:left;
}
#menu a{
 display:table;
 width:25%;
 float:left;
}
#fake a{
 width:100%;
 display:table;
}
#social a{
 float:right;
 width:33.33%;
}
#menu a,#social a,#fake a{
 text-decoration:none;  
 margin:0;
 padding:5px;
 color:white;
 text-align:center;
}
.rMargin{
 margin-right:10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->   
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Skranji" rel="stylesheet"> 
  </head>
  <body>
      
    <header>
      <div id="nav">
        <div id="menu">
          <a class="active" href="home.html"><i class="fas fa-home rMargin"></i>Home</a>
          <a href="blog.html"><i class="fas fa-globe rMargin"></i>Blog</a>
          <a href="learn.html"><i class="fas fa-code rMargin"></i>Learn</a>
          <a href="contactMe.html"><i class="fas fa-envelope rMargin"></i>Contact Me</a>  
        </div> 

        <div id="fake" >
          <a class="active fake" href="#"><button style="visibility:hidden"></button></a>
        </div>

        <div id="social">               
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a> 
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>                                
        </div>
      </div>        
      </header>

    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-+d0P83n9kaQMCwj8F4RJB66tzIwOKmrdb46+porD/OvrJ+37WqIM7UoBtwHO6Nlg" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```